# How can you check SPF lookup limit via bash

Tags: email, spf

I'm trying to build a bash script to check SPF records and so far I have managed to create one to check if there is an SPF record and the type of the SPF record (PASS, SOFT FAIL and FAIL) but I'm trying to figure out how to also check if an SPF record has too many lookups included, let me know if anyone knows a ready-made script for that or perhaps knows a way to do that check. Thanks

Comment: You can use my https://crates.io/crates/spftrace utility.

Comment: hey @glts is there any further documentation for the tool that I can use? I need to understand a way to only show a couple of things when the script is run but I can't find anything in-depth that might help me with that. Thanks